# Cannot find method in inner class

Tags: java

My code:

```
 public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
   private Thread spawnRnn = new Thread(new SpawnRnn());

   public MyPanel() {
     spawnRnn.start();
   }

   public class SpawnRnn implements Runnable {
     public void loadData() {}
     public void run() {}
   }
   public class MainRnn implements Runnable {
     public void run() {
       spawnRnn.loadData(); //<--cannot find symbol. symbol: method loadData()
                            //location: variable spawnRnn of type Thread
     }
   }
}
```

I pointed place where error occurs. What is the reason and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's an easy one. "spawnRnn" is of type "Thread", not "SpawnRnn"

Comment: I also tried to do: private Runnable spawnRnn = new SpawnRnn() and soesnt work too. Just shows another error EDIT: ah, it should be SpawnRnn not Runnable... My mistake

Comment: @user2080377: Well again, in that case `spawnRnn` wouldn't have a member called `loadData` - just `run()`.

Answer (score 2):

As the compiler says, `spawnRnn` is of type `Thread`, not of type `SpawnRnn`... it doesn't have a `loadData` method. You probably want something like this:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
   private final Thread thread;
   private final SpawnRnn spawnRnn;

   public MyPanel() {
      spawnRnn = new SpawnRnn();
      thread = new Thread(spawnRnn);
      thread.start();
   }

   public class SpawnRnn implements Runnable {
     public void loadData() {}
     public void run() {}
   }

   public class MainRnn implements Runnable {
     public void run() {
       spawnRnn.loadData();
     }
   }
}
```

This way you have access to the instance of `SpawnRnn` which was used to create the thread. It's unclear whether you actually need the `thread` variable, or whether you could just use a local variable in the constructor.

(Also I've made the variables final on the grounds that when you *can* do so, it makes the code easier to reason about.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that spawnRnn is of type Thread not SpawnRnn.